# Multiple Web application R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Assuming I have 2 action buttons as a starting page 'Client' & 'Employee' as shown below, and for each option, there is a different web application.
[image]

when the user clicks the 'Client' button I need the following code to be run:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- 
navbarPage(
"The Client Web",
tabPanel("Section1 "),
tabPanel(" Section1 2")
)

server <- function(input, output,session){

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and when the user clicks the 'Employee' button I need the following code to be run:

```
 library(shiny)

 ui <- 
 navbarPage(
 "The Employee Web",
 tabPanel("Component 1"),
 tabPanel("Component 2"),
  tabPanel("Component 3")
  )

  server <- function(input, output,session){

  }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I need both of the web applications in one app depending on the type of the user either 'Client' or 'Employee'. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using JavaScript

I would do it using Javascript code to hide/show either of the pages.

You have to create your app with de buttons and both navbarpages.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Buttons
  actionButton('clientsBtn', 'Clients'),
  actionButton('employeeBtn', 'Employee'),
  
  # Employee pag
  div(
    class = 'employees-page',
    navbarPage(
      "The Employee Web",
      tabPanel("Component 1"),
      tabPanel("Component 2"),
      tabPanel("Component 3")
    )
  ),
  
  # Clients page
  div(
    class = 'clients-page',
    navbarPage(
      "The Client Web",
      tabPanel("Section1 "),
      tabPanel(" Section1 2")
    )
  ),

  # Javascript to control de page logic
includeScript('script.js')
)

server <- function(input, output,session){
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The script.js file is just a text file with that extension.

```js
// hide by default the clients page
$('.clients-page').hide(); 

$('#clientsBtn').on('click', () => { 
  $('.employees-page').hide(); 
  $('.clients-page').show();
})

$('#employeeBtn').on('click', ()=>{ 
  $('.employees-page').show(); 
  $('.clients-page').hide(); 
})
```

[image]

### Individual pages using shiny.router

As I promised, here is the approach using `{shiny.router}` to accomplish what you want.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shiny.router)

# The root page is separated from clients and employee pages
# and contains two buttons/links that takes you the destination
# you wish

root_page <- tagList(
  tags$a(
  div(class='btn btn-default', id='clientsBtn', 'Clients'),
  href=route_link('clients')
  ),
  
  tags$a(
    div(class='btn btn-default', id='employeeBtn', 'Employee'), 
    href=route_link('employees')
    )
)

# The employee and clients page should include a button/link
# to take you back to the root page. I place the button in the
# first tabpanel of each page, but for better ux is good idea
# if you place it in all of them. Consider change its style and
# position using css configuration.

employee_page <- tagList(
  navbarPage(
    "The Employee Web",
    tabPanel(
      "Component 1",
      tags$a(
        div(class='btn btn-default', id='home1', 'Home'), 
        href=route_link('/')
      )
      ),
    tabPanel("Component 2"),
    tabPanel("Component 3")
  )
)


clients_page <- tagList(
  navbarPage(
    "The Client Web",
    tabPanel(
      "Section1 ",
      tags$a(
        div(class='btn btn-default', id='home1', 'Home'), 
        href=route_link('/')
      )
      ),
    tabPanel(" Section1 2")
  )
)

router <- make_router(
  route("/", root_page),
  route("employees", employee_page),
  route("clients", clients_page)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  router$ui
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  router$server(input, output, session)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Johan. This definitely will solve my problem. Still, I need the two buttons 'Clients' & 'Employee'to be on a separate page and after clicking one of them I need to see either the 'The Client Web' or 'The Employee Web'. I would be very grateful if you could assist me on this regard

Comment: I will help you with that as well later. You can take a look on [{shiny.router}](https://appsilon.com/shiny-router-package/), a package that helps with that.

Comment: Thank you again! I really appreciate your efforts. I have tried to apply {shiny. router} but the final result was the same as you did!

Comment: you can see my answer below

Comment: Done, now my answer include the solution you were looking for. Welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: I am really grateful. I have nothing to say but thank you very much.
Your answer did not solve my problem only but it also has motivated my willingness for helping other people with whatever I am good at as you do.

Comment: Hi Johan. I need your help again. is it possible to nest the make_router function I mean to have make_router inside the 
    make_router like this:router <- make_router(
  route("/", root_page),
        route("employees", employee_page),
        route(make_router( route("clients",type_of_clients),
                   route('norclients',normal_clients_page),
                   route('vipnclients',vip_clients_page))

           ))  # I have tried this but it did not work!

Comment: I haven't done that before. But, do you really need that? you can ask in the main page if the client is normal or VIP. And, by the way, it seems that your app will be used by people with different profile, I recommend you to consider a data base wit the user information and depending on that display te pages they should see.  Pakages like [{firebase}(https://firebase.john-coene.com/) would help you.

Comment: Just create add the VIP and normal pages in the original router and use the links were you need.

Answer (score 0):

I got theses result:[image]

[image]

when I have tried the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.router)


Cleints_page <- div(
titlePanel("Cleints"),
p("This is the Cleints web app")
)

Employees_page <- div(
titlePanel("Employees"),
p("This is the Employees web app")
)

router <- make_router(
route("/", Cleints_page),
route("employees", Employees_page)
)


 ui <- fluidPage(
 tags$ul(
  tags$li(a(href = route_link("/"), "Cleints 
  Web")),
  tags$li(a(href = route_link("employees"), 
  "Employees Web"))
  
  ),
  router$ui
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
  router$server(input, output, session)
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

but still, I need each one of them to be a separate page. How I can achieve that?

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you Hamed. the above answer under the title of "Individual pages using shiny.router" have met my needs.